# Dropdown options from Angular Form to Json Format?

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in angular form, Which will have options defined as id,label
So when i select the dropdown i need to store only label value to the ng-model

Here is my code

```
titleOptions = [{id: 1, label: 'Mr'},
               {id: 2, label: 'Mrs'},
                {id: 3, label: 'Ms'}];



<label for="title">Title*</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="title" ng-options="title.label for title in titleOptions track by title.id" ng-required="true" value="" ng-init="titleOptions">
```

if i select the title my ng-model title is like {id:1,label:Mr}
It is creating problem in json structure. In my json structure it should come as title:'Mr'

Comment: You can use `title.label` where you use your model?

Comment: That is not working Jins. In screen i am able to select but in Json it is same as {id:1,label:'Mr' only}. I want in Json title:'Mr' only. It should not take id.

Comment: What i mean is use you same code. and use title.label where you had been using the object 'title' in th controller